# What is the best way to search within datastore entities?

Tags: google-app-engine, search, full-text-search, datastore

I am building a website similar to yellow pages were users or visitors can search for registered companies. My website uses GAE datastore to store Companies information. I am a bit confused about the way, the API or the mechanism which I will use to implement something like full text search with my website. I will give you an example:
suppose we have 3 companies

1. name: name11, Address: address11, Activity: activity11.
2. name: bla bla co. , Address: USE Chicago ... , Activity: house
   serving.
3. name: some other Ltd, Address: Bulgaria, Activity: Software
   development.

and I have a search bar and the user enter the following text: house serving bulgaria name11.

1. What is the best way to save Company entities, so that I can get
   information easy when search?
2. What is the best mechanism to search my companies properties?
3. I also want to look into some long text within companies profiles
   like some description or something.

Comment: Have you looked at the fulltext search API? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/overview

Comment: Yes, but they say that it is experimental. So I decided to ask perhaps some pros have some other ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use full-text search for this. The alternative, datastore, will be too inflexible and expensive (code-wise and penny-wise) to maintain.

I saw that you are concerned about full-text search being experimental, but it is unlikely that is will see major changes to the API in the future. I don't know about future pricing, but I think implementing a similarly functional feature with datastore won't be cheaper (indexes will cost you, in-memory searches will cost you instance time)